# Hand-built timer for Xamarin Forms?

Tags: .net, xamarin, timer

Is it possible to build your own timer for Xamarin Forms without using System.Threading or System.Timers?

I'm trying to do just that and used the code below, however it seems to count far too fast, is there another approach I could take?

It's for a PCL project on .Net 4.5.

```
public class TimerHelper
{
    public class Timer
    {
        private int _waitTime;
        public int WaitTime
        {
            get { return _waitTime; }
            set { _waitTime = value; }
        }

        private bool _isRunning;
        public bool IsRunning
        {
            get { return _isRunning; }
            set { _isRunning = value; }
        }

        public event EventHandler Elapsed;

        public virtual void OnTimerElapsed(int _autoSwipes, int _swipes)
        {
            if (Elapsed != null)
            {
                Elapsed(this, new EventArgs());
                if (_autoSwipes < _swipes)
                {
                    Stop();
                    Start(_autoSwipes, _swipes);
                }
                else
                {
                    Task.WaitAll();//MoveNext);
                    _autoSwipes++;
                }
            }
        }

        public Timer(int waitTime)
        {
            WaitTime = waitTime;
        }

        public async Task Start(int _autoSwipes, int _swipes)
        {

            int seconds = 0;
            IsRunning = true;
            while (IsRunning)
            {
                if (seconds != 0 && seconds % WaitTime == 0)
                {
                    OnTimerElapsed(_autoSwipes, _swipes);
                }
                seconds++;
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            IsRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're just incrementing "seconds" in a loop, there is nothing to govern how fast that loop cycles.

Comment: exactly, so without using the 2 libraries I mentioned is there any way to do this?

Comment: I did try to use Device.StartTimer, this does half of what I need but I can't reinitialize it when certain conditions are met.  If I do rreinitialize (by returning false, then starting again) I'm guessing that's going to fire off on a different thread rather than start the original timer?  How about doing something with Timespan.Ticks?

Comment: you could look at how mono implements it's Timer class.  Or you could use a PCL timer nuget package - there are a couple.  Or implement the timer in platform code and use DI to access it from your PCL.

Comment: thanks, I'll look at the DI option.  Every nugget package I tried failed due to the .NET version.